# What is the meaning of "steep horizontal pressure gradient"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I could not solve the meaning of *steep* in this phrase:

> *Steep* horizontal pressure gradient.

Could you paraphrase the sentence or give me the synonym of this word meaning in this sentence?

Comment: Pressure changes very much and very fast as you go from one end of the range to the other end.

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gradient. The pressure is the parameter that changes rapidly. Horizontal is presumably the axis over which it changes rapidly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Horizontal pressure gradient" is a technical term.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_gradient), "The **horizontal pressure gradient** is a 2-dimensional vector resulting from the projection of the pressure gradient onto a local horizontal plane."

When we say *"**steep** horizontal pressure gradient"*, we simply mean that it's **strong**. For example,

> **HORIZONTAL PRESSURE GRADIENT**.— The  horizontal  pressure  gradient  is  *steep*  or  *strong* when the isobars determining the pressure system (fig. 3-7)  are  close  together.  It  is  *flat*  or  *weak*  when  the isobars are far apart.
>   <sub>Source: http://meteorologytraining.tpub.com/14312/css/14312_65.htm</sub>

Answer (score 5):

Presumably, pressure is indicated on the **horizontal** or **x-axis**.
Steepness is defined by how quickly it changes per unit moving along the x-axis.

In the graph, substitute Pressure" for "Distance".

[image: here]
<sub>(source: [tulane.edu](http://www.tulane.edu/~sanelson/images/longprof.gif))</sub>